# class equals variable name

Tags: jquery, class, variables

I have the following code:

```
var theclass="class1";

$("#div0").append('<div class=theclass id="div1"></div>');
```

I want the class of div1 to be equal to the variable, but that isn't working.
The problem is class=theclass, I don't know why this isn't working. 
Please help, thanks.

Comment: Please learn javascript before jQuery!

Comment: @Pinocchio Calm down :) Everyone has to learn.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$("#div0").append('<div class="'+ theclass +'" id="div1"></div>');
```

This is the easiest way. An alternative:

```
var $div = $('<div/>').prop({ 'class': theclass, 'id': 'div1' });
$('#div0').append($div);
```

Or even in a one-liner:

```
 $('<div/>').prop({ 'class': theclass, 'id': 'div1' }).appendTo('#div0');
```

Note: `prop()` is not supported in older versions of jQuery. If it's not supported in your version, use `attr()`

Comment: You can also pass those attributes as the second argument to the jQuery function. Like this http://jsfiddle.net/zZLV2/

Comment: @Pinocchio Yes, but I use to avoid it, since IE7 is having some problems with it.

Comment: Really!? How *can* IE7 have problems with it?

Comment: @Kobi Hahah :) Dude, you made me spill coffee over my keyboard ... Still laughing :)

Comment: Maybe IE7 Thinks **"No, i don't like that! Use a plugin!**!

Comment: Anyway IE7 should have been dead a long time ago.

Comment: @Pinocchio I'm afraid that IE7 is still "alive". IE6, however, is dead.

Comment: The reason it's still alive is because everyone protects and looks after it. if they didn't it would be dead.